# ADsDSOObject & .NET return different values (types) for objectSID

Tags: sql-server, powershell, adsi

I have a user created stored procedure in a database server that queries active directory for user information and inserts the data into a table.  We wish to remove the operation from the database server and perform the initial AD query and data insert in an external call (PowerShell or C#).

The stored procedure uses the sp_OA procedures to create an ADsDSOObject to do the actual AD query.  It appears that the ADsDSOObject is returning the objectSID in hex by default.  Following is an example output value.

```
-- ADsDSOObject: 0x010500000000000515000000D94242061941C67FC9004A20EE030000
```

When I run an ADSI query through PowerShell, I get a byte array for the objectSID which I can turn into a string via the .NET System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier (`<objectSID>`, 0).

This returns the actual string SID identifier in it's proper SID form.

```
-- Byte Array: {1, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 21, 0, 0, 0, 217, 66, 66, 6, 25, 65, 198, 127, 201, 0, 74, 32, 245, 1, 0, 0}

-- .NET SID: S-1-5-21-105005785-2143699225-541720777-501
```

However, I need to store the data as binary in order to replace the procedure in the database with a .NET solution in order to avoid any changes in the application.

Using PowerShell or C#, does anyone know how to either convert the byte array to hex or how to convert the string SID representation to hex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution :

```
PS> $sid = New-Object System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier ("S-1-5-21-105005785-2143699225-541720777-501")
PS> $c = New-Object 'byte[]' $sid.BinaryLength
PS> $sid.GetBinaryForm($c, 0)
```

$c contains the byte array you need.

Comment: You are wellcome, if so can you put the answer as good answer ?